# Fullcalendar event placement and layout

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to implement a design where each fullcalendar event is represented by a pushpin image. I would like to be able to add multiple events to any date (in month view), so that the pushpins line up horizontally. By default, each event appears to be in a div, and no way to specify float "left".  I assume it will be necessary to modify the javascript, but am wondering if anyone else has already worked on this problem. Thanks for any help at all!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hint to solve your problem. 
You need to change following functions to update left and width of you event element.

```
  function daySegHTML // this function create your event element with div
  function colContentLeft //  function calculate left position of event element
  function daySegSetWidths // function set width for you event element. you can restrict width for element 

  e.g. Math.max(0, seg.outerWidth - seg.hsides) / ( how many event you want to place in one row )
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid that but I agree, looks like that's what it will have to be.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but it sounds like all you need to do is use .append() on the element in eventRender.

Example:

```
eventRender: function( event, element, view ){
  element.append('<div style="float:left;">/*push pin image*/</div>');
}
```

According to the docs, element is the newly created div for the event
Let me know if this is what you were talking about, if not clarify and I'll try to further assist you.

Comment: I think that would indeed align the pins visually, but there needs to be a separate pin for each event, as clicking on a pin brings up a form associated with the pin. The calendar is for COPD patients logging symptoms, exercises, changes in meds, etc. and each log type will have a color-coded pin to represent it in the calendar.  There may be a way to accomplish this with multiple pins in a single event, but as the event's custom attributes are so different, it made sense to try to have a single pin per event type. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but if the form is different per event type, than just use an enum in the database to determine which type it is, then use a switch statement or ifelse to determine which pin and corresponding form goes with the event. Does that help

Comment: Yes - you understand perfectly how it operates. I already have that part working though, and just need to change so that each event is represented in the calendar as a pin, in place of text (that part is working too). I would just like to be able to align the pins within a calendar day horizontally.  As it is right now, they stack vertically, as you would expect divs to do. If i could find a way to get them to align float:left, i'd be home free. Maybe it's as simple as setting the css of each event to float left, then tacking on an empty event with clear:both.

Comment: It should be that easy, if not, than use the span tag or the css display: inline-block; on the div coupled with vertical-align:top on event div

Comment: Ok I will try that, and will let you know how it turns out. Thanks a million!

Comment: Hi David, how did you go with your query? I am actually looking to have my events side by side per day in the month view. Cheers